# Using a queue in a multithreaded situation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue, race-condition

I just **learned about [queues in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(VS.71).aspx)** and I have a few questions.

Let's say that I'm building an application that downloads the HTML of pages and then processes it. Here's how I want it to operate:

1. A main thread adds URLs to a queue
2. This queue is read by two other threads. They "dequeue" a URL and then download the corresponding HTML.
3. The HTML is then sent back to the main thread.
4. When the HTML arrives in the main thread, it is placed into another queue, handled by another two threads. These threads process the HTML.
5. The results of the processing are returned to the main thread.

---

How can I **implement such a scenario without the possibility of a race condition?**

Also, what is the best way to pass the information between queues and threads as described above?

Could you give me some **sample code**?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Comment: Why do the first set of threads need to send the HTML back to the main thread? It seems like you possibly want multiple queues because it smells like you're building some kind of processing pipeline. You typically have a queue between each step in the pipeline.

Comment: Depending on the scenario (I get that this is hypothetical), you might also consider not having dedicated threads for certain tasks like this and instead take a TPL-based ("thread-agile") approach where you might have download tasks that ContinueWith processing tasks and then consume the result (ContinueWithAll, or ContinueWith, or whatever depending on if you wanted to act per-result or wait for all results).  See TPL @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx and DownloadStringTask @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/23/10001621.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). It represents a "producer/consumer queue" common in multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to mind.

The first is to use a collection that implements locking to produce thread safe consistency (such as BlockingCollection as mentioned elsewhere).

The second is to use an immutable collection (such as the ones described by Eric Lippart in [Link](https://ericlippert.com/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/) ) which avoids most of the hassle of thread locking and race conditions in the first place and makes what's ever left over a little more obvious usually.